# What is Padme's reaction to Jar Jar's part in starting the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-clone-wars, attack-of-the-clones

When the CIS army was discovered, it was Jar Jar who motioned for Supreme Chancellor Palpatine to be granted the emergency powers necessary to create a Grand Army of the Republic, thus arming both sides, a step necessary to starting war.

As a pacifist who believes in peaceful negotiations and the democratic process, what was Padme's reaction when she found out what transpired while she was away?

Legends answer acceptable.

Comment: I would say that arming both sides was necessary to avoid a quick *end* to the war with a Separatist victory. Without the GAR, the Separatists could have easily captured Coruscant and deposed the government of the Republic. I don't see how that's preferable for the Republic. Palpatine's genius strikes again: he wins either way.

Comment: It might also be a plot hole...

Comment: She was like “You’ll return to my service *over my dead body*” and Jar-Jar walked off muttering “Mesah can wait” under his breath.

Answer (score 9):

I've not been able to find a reference to any event between Amidala and Jar Jar in relation to this specific event.  Amidala doesn't have much going on in the Legends universe, unfortunately.

However, in The Clone Wars TV show, she interacts with Jar Jar professionally.  Not overly fond or hostile.  She also seems to accept that Jar Jar is a few pixels short of a low res jpeg.  For example, Jar Jar destroys her starship and she takes it in stride (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:ShipHasBeenDestroyed-BJ.ogg).

Here's the supposition:  As an experienced senator, she knows the back room machinations involved in just about every vote.  She also knows that Jar Jar is innocent and oblivious to a fault.  At the end of the day, it would be blindingly clear that Jar Jar was manipulated by the opposing side, that her activism had never succeeded at pushing the pacifism side over the voting threshold, and that the Republic Army turned out to be a necessary evil.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already it is so that we just dont have any concrete infos there.
Although we can take into consideration how she racts to him in the series.

She reacts there to him in the same ways as in the movies. Which means it didn't hamper their friendly relationship at all. Also she is not one to hold grudges or to hold one up to errors and mistakes one made. That is how she managed to forgive many of the CIS time and again and tried to push for freedom.

Thus all in all: She herself would have chosen a different path, but she has seemingly accepted what Jarjar did and why. She accepted this but has a differing oppinion on the correct course of the actions that should have been taken.

Additionally Jarjar is sort of a mary sue like character time and again......he should have died multiple times during the films and the series and survived in ways that would have put ANY jedi master to shame (he even once believingly played one......by pure accident again). So even if it would have been out of character for Padme she would have been bound to forgive him anyway (as everyone did regardless what he destroyed or whom he almost killed).

Answer (score -2):

I think that senator Amidala might have been mad at Jar Jar for some time, but then Palpatine gave her one of those private manipulative speeches and she agreed that what done is done. Also in season 1 episode 8 Bombad Jedi she is like: Jar Jar. It would be best if you stayed on the ship. But meesa would be great help with the negotiations. Jar Jar. Please. Maybe she didn't take him because she was worried that he will do something like that again.

Comment: The second part is possibly of interest (if you could back it up with something from the commentary track, perhaps) but the first bit is pure speculation.